# How To Store Key Value In MAP As Pair In C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve a question on hacker rank named (Attribute Parser) : [QUESTION](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/attribute-parser/problem)

So I came up with a solution that I could use **map** but in order to solve it I need to insert two keys 1 would be pair and the other would be a string
`map<pair<string,string>,string>DATA;`

I tried `DATA.emplace({Type, Tag},Data);`

But it's giving an error:

> no matching member function for call to 'emplace'

Now how to insert elements as well as access them?

Comment: Use `std::make_pair` instead of `{Type,Tag}`. Also, you should use spaces. And don't use `ALLUPPERCASE` names like `DATA` - those are reserved for `#define` macros.

Comment: Thanks @Dai It Worked Can You Post It As A Answer So It Could Help Others Too

Comment: For a `map<pair<string,string>,string>`, you would be inserting one key (the pair) and one **value** (the string).

Comment: Related, but a bit simpler as it deals with a pair of `int`s instead of `string`s: [How to insert pair into map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311881/how-to-insert-pair-into-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DATA.emplace({Type, Tag},Data);
```

There is no implicit conversion to `std::pair<string,string>` from `{Type,Tag}` even if they are of `string` type. Rather use `std::make_pair`

```
DATA.emplace(std::make_pair(Type,Tag), Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing DATA.emplace({Type, Tag},Data);

//Inserting Element

Try

```
DATA.emplace(make_pair(Type, Tag),Data);
```

And To Access It:

//storing pair in variable

```
pair<string, string> Value(Type, Tag);
cout<<DATA[Value];
```